# Edubuntu installation setup fail

Tags: grub2, raid, edubuntu

I'm having too many problems with my project.

Let me explain it.

I have just bought a brand new HP Proliant Ml310e Gen8 v2 server with 32 MB of RAM on a RAID 1 system (3TB + 3TB)  to deploy an Edubuntu on a PXE environment.

Firstly, when I began the installation on my server using the HP Dynamic Smart Array B120i Raid controller, the wizard detected two drives, and not the ONE logical volume I created. I decided to install in the first drive. Everything looks okay until when I rebooted my computer that `GRUB RESCUE` prompt appeared with:

```
error: out of disk
grub rescue
```

No way to go forward. I have tried this: https://wiki.edubuntu.org/Raid but it didn't work at all.

So I decided to destroy my array. Use single drive and once I get installed my **edubuntu** system just make a SOFTWARE RAID 1, but...

again the same error:

```
error: out of disk
grub rescue
```

I also tried grub rescue disk without any result.

I'm really lost, and the only thing I do is loose my time. I would appreciate any help or, if anybody had the same problem with this HP server and got the solution it would be great if shares the solution here for all us.

Regards,

Jose Manuel Alfonso

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a fake raid controller.  Blow away the array in the bios and set up a software raid during install.